# If $\Delta u - u \geq 0$ in $D$, show that $u\leq \max\{\ \max\limits_{\partial D}(u), \ 0 \ \}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle

Let $D$ be a bounded domain, with boundary $\partial D$.

Suppose $u \in C^{2}(D)\cap C^{0}(D\cup\partial D)$ satisfies $\Delta u - u \geq 0$ in all of $D$.

I am supposed to prove then that $u\leq \max\{\ \max\limits_{\partial D}(u), \ 0 \ \}$.

MY ATTEMPT:

I think that:

$\max \{ \max\limits_{C} u , 0 \} = \max\limits_{C} u \ \ \ \ $ when $\max\limits_{C} u > 0$

$\max \{ \max\limits_{C} u , 0 \} = 0 \ \ \ \ $ when $\max\limits_{C} u \leq 0$

So I thought about treating these cases seperately, however I get stuck.

$\ $

The maximum of $u$ must occur in $D\cup \partial D$.

Suppose that $\mathbf{p} \in D$ is a maximum of $u$. Then $u_{x}(\mathbf{p})=u_{y}(\mathbf{p})=0$, and also, $u_{xx}(\mathbf{p})\leq 0$ and $u_{yy}(\mathbf{p})\leq 0$ (since $\mathbf{p}$ is a maximum).

Then I find that $u_{xx}(\mathbf{p})+ u_{yy}(\mathbf{p}) \leq 0$, which means that $\Delta u(\mathbf{p}) \leq 0$.

This is where I get stuck.

I'm trying to get a contradiction using this method. If I can only say that $u$ is positive then $\Delta u(\mathbf{p})- u \leq 0$ is immediate, and we have a contradiction (meaning that $\mathbf{p} \in D$ cannot be a maximum and the maximum must occur on the boundary $\partial D$.). But I can't figure out why.

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to worry about the set where $u\le 0$ because the inequality is automatic there. On the open set $U=\{x : u>0 \}$ (possibly empty), $\Delta u\ge 0$, so $u$ is subharmonic on $U$ and thus satisfies the maximum principle there. So $u\le\max_{\partial U}u$ on $U$, but the boundary of $U$ is contained in $\partial D\cup U^c$, so we obtain the desired estimate.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've got a few questions: Why exactly is $U=\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} | u(\mathbf{x})>0\}$ an open set?

Comment: Next Question, why is $\Delta u \geq 0$ on $U$?

Comment: When you say the boundary of $U$ is contained in $\partial D \cup U^{c}$, you mean that $U^{c}=U - D$? And how exactly does the estimate follow from that? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: $U$ is the inverse image of an open set under a continuous map, so it's open; $\Delta u\ge u\ge 0$; $U^c:=D\setminus U$.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake above, I meant $U=\{ \ \mathbf{x} \in D\ |\ u(\mathbf{x})>0 \}$. That all makes great sense, thank you very much. However, how does $\partial U \subset \partial D \cup U^{c}$ imply $u\leq \max\{\ \max\limits_{\partial D}(u), \ 0 \ \}$?

Comment: Thinking about it further, I would agree that $u(D)$ is an open set, since $D$ is an open set and $u$ is continuous. But if we put a restriction defining the set $U$ as above, then how can we be sure that $U$ is open?

Comment: $U$ is open as a subset of the closed disk, in the relative topology, is what I'm saying.